# How to properly print Haskell record containing UTF-8 Text?

Tags: haskell, utf-8

I have a following Haskell record:

```hs
import Data.Text (Text)

data Person = Person
  { name :: Text
  , age :: Int
  }
  deriving (Show)

secondPerson :: Person
secondPerson =
  Person
    { name = "हर्षल पाटील"
    , age = 100
    }
```

For my name, I am using the non-english (of course, UTF-8) characters. But when I print using:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main =
  putStrLn "Second Person"
    *> print secondPerson
```

I get some encoded output:

```
Second Person
Person {name = "\2361\2352\2381\2359\2354 \2346\2366\2335\2368\2354", age = 100}
```

What is the way properly print this in Haskell? I may have multiple records with any number of text fields and need a generic way to achieve this.

Comment: The record doesn't contain UTF-8 text, it just contains abstractly Unicode text. (The _source file_ is in UTF-8, and you presumably want the output to be UTF-8 as well.) IMO `print` should just not bother escaping printable non-ASCII Unicode, but it does. Some people would argue that it shouldn't matter, that `print`/`show` should just give a reliable, consistent representation, which this one is. But it's certainly very reading-unfriendly.

Comment: You'll have to define your own instance of `Show`, or another `String`-returning function to use instead of `show`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
putStrLn ("Person " ++ name secondPerson ++ " " ++ show age)
```

instead of `print`. Depending on your OS and terminal, this might give you the output you seek.

The issue here is that `print` call `show`, and `show` prints strings by escaping most characters which are not ASCII alphanumeric ones. Basically, `show` is designed so that it always outputs an ASCII string in an unambiguous form, including escaping quotes and other non-simple characters.

If you want to print more characters, you need therefore to avoid `show`/`print` and format your output manually, then call the lower level `putStrLn` (or `putStr`) which outputs a string as it is.

Comment: `show` / the `Show` class isn't really designed with any preferrence for ASCII, just for valid Haskell source code. The documentation doesn't mention ASCII. It's specifically the `Show Char` instance that takes this over-cautious approach (and libraries such as `text` have copied it). I'd say this is quite outdated.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I see. So the ASCII preference is only an implementation choice and not some hard guarantee from the documentation/specs/report. IIRC, on Windows trying to output anything non ASCII on the terminal can be tricky, though, so having an ASCII default could be a pragmatic solution. Personally, I'd love if unicode just worked everywhere.

Comment: Ah yes. Well, I'd love if people just didn't use Windows...

Comment: So, it means that there is not generic function or TypeClass method that can handle this well (works with any data type) with UTF-8 in mind, doesn't it?

Comment: @HarshalPatil Converting to UTF8 is one thing, and produces a sequence of bytes. Printing that string as unicode characters on the terminal is another thing, which is not necessarily related to converting to UTF8 (e.g. because the terminal only accepts another encoding, or does not support Unicode).